# Problems with SVN with a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I was working with a project that I was uploading the source to a SVN repo.

For a few weeks I dind`t uploaded any code.

My computer has broken.

I could access to the HD and recover my eclipse project.

Now if I import my project into Eclipse and I want to synchronize with my repo, all my files appear to be in conflicts.

Is there any way that I could "clean" my recovered project so I can stop having conflicts and in this way start to sync my project again with my repo?

When I open a file to see the changes, in those files, where I know that there is no change between my local file and the repo file, my local file version is lower than the repo file, example (local file version: 244 and repo version: 351). But there is no change between one and another file.

How can I get my project working again with my repo?

Comment: before trying a merge or anything, try doing a team >> update first. that might bring most of your files up to life

Comment: if the repo version number is different than your local number, then probably someone changed the code in the repository since your last update. try to do what @Ibrahim Diallo says and tell us the output.

Answer (score 2):

First do a team -> cleanup on your project. This sometimes resolves some SVN-specific tree issues.

Then go to the team synchronization perspective and do an update of the complete project.

Select the conflicts tab and resolve each conflicted file, there are two options: 'override and update' (dismiss your local changes and continue with the repository version) or
'mark as merged' (indicate that your local file is correct, and the repository version should be overwritten)

Before selecting 'mark as merged' you can use the diff tool to view each discrepancy in turn and edit your local file if necessary. Note that the diff tool has a setting 'ignore whitespace' which might help reduce the clutter.

After you are done, before committing anything re-build the project from scratch and run all your tests.

If you still get stuck there is a more drastic solution: make a fresh checkout of the project in another directory and then copy your local changes into it by hand. **Make sure you don't copy any .svn directories!**